# Script to disable any key on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, script

How to write a script to disable keys on Mac? Is there any script to do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do?  What keys are you trying to disable?  is it a particular application?

Without context, the best answer you may receive is unplug the keyboard...

Comment: haha well, its like disabling all the keys on the keyboard except for command key and few other keys. But it should be through a script, something like registries or vbscript which is used in windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get what you're looking for by remapping the key bindings.  See [Jacob Rus'  key bindings tutorial for details.](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html)